# Ontotext GraphDB colors of individuals in Visual Graph

Tags: ontology, semantic-web, graph-visualization, graphdb

I have been trying to visualize a set of individuals of different types using Ontotext GraphDB. The problem is that all of them are visualized as red circles, since they are all identified as of type `owl:namedIndividual`, while they also belong to more specific types - see screenshot below for an example:

[image: screenshot of an individual from Ontotext GraphDB]

I would like the different types to be visualized using different colors. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926247/how-does-ontotext-graphdb-assign-colors-in-visual-graph
I hope this will help.

Comment: @KonstantinPetrov many thanks for the link, I have already seen this question and the responses. I am afraid I want something slightly different: I want to be able to have GraphDB assign colors depending on the type of the instance. I don't care about the color itself, I just want e.g. 'observation' individuals to be of different color than 'sensor' individuals.

Comment: Check the `Node basics` tab of your visual graph config. Nodes with different values for `?type` variable will have different colors. You may try to use `sesame:directType` instead of `rdf:type` so that the most specific type is selected and thus instances of one and the same type will have same colours ...